# box-shadow - Only get border bottom instead of right and bottom - why?

Tags: css

I wish to have on a given div, a shadow on the **bottom** and **right** sides.

```
#navigation-and-slideshow {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 1%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #222;
}
```

I'm only getting bottom on all tested browsers. 
Can anyone help me solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: A fiddle might help. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Vfgsz/ . Your code does work there. But I had to specify a height and width. That might be your problem

Comment: it works if I only place width at 97% or less. I don't understand why, so the question remains. :(

Comment: Probably because there isn't any space left on the right if your width is more than 97%

Answer (score 0):

Your div's width is sprawling across the entire width of the browser window. In Firefox and Chrome, the shadow is considered outside the total window area and therefore cannot be seen. In Opera, the window area is increased to accommodate the shadows. A scrollbar will appear in the browser window. If you scroll to the right, you shall see the right border shadow.